# Need to convert Perl unpack to Inline::C AV*

Tags: perl, inline-c

I am struggling a bit to convert a Perl `unpack` to Inline::C

```
@array = unpack("C*", $buf);
```

This is what I have so far, but I am an Inline::C novice so I am having trouble of what to do next:

```
STRLEN len;
char* test = SvPVbyte(buf, len);
...
AV* arr = SvRV(?);
```

Can anyone provide a tip to how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smart thing here is probably to avoid calling `unpack`, and do what `unpack` would do, which is simpler.

```
STRLEN len;
char *str = SvPVbyte(buf, len);
AV *arr = newAV();
char *ptr;

for (ptr = str; ptr < str + len ; ptr++) {
    SV *char_value = newSViv(*ptr);
    av_push(arr, char_value);
}
```

Or, of course, just write the loop and leave out the array if you don't need it :)

Answer (score 2):

The body of the function could look like:

```
STRLEN len;
char*  buf;
AV*    av = newAV();

SvGETMAGIC(sv);
buf = SvPVbyte(sv, len);
while (len--)
    av_push(av, newSViv(*(buf++)));
```

You have two choices for the return value.

```
SV* my_unpack(SV* sv) {
    ...
    return newRV_noinc(av);  // Will get mortalized by typemap.
}
```

or

```
AV* my_unpack(SV* sv) {
    ...
    return sv_2mortal(av);  // Typemap will create a reference.
}
```